# Как при клике на элемент RecyclerView показать другую вьюшку?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

От api получаю данные, на первичном экране отображаются только три поля: изображение контакта, имя и номер телефона, как сделать так чтобы при клике на каждого контакта открывалась другая вьюшка с подробной информацией: имя, фамилия, изображение, почта, заметки, номер телефона и т.д.?

Adapter на данный момент выглядит так:

```
class ContactsAdapter (private val context: Context, private val mContactsList: ArrayList<Contacts> = ArrayList())
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    fun setupContacts(contactsList: ArrayList<Contacts>) {
        mContactsList.clear()
        mContactsList.addAll(contactsList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_contact, parent, false)
        return ContactsViewHolder(itemView = itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mContactsList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is ContactsViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(contactsModel = mContactsList[position])
        }
    }

    class ContactsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mContactIcon: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image)
        var mContactFirstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_first_name)
        var mContactPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)

        fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
            contactsModel.images?.let { url ->
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                    .into(mContactIcon)
            }
            mContactFirstName.text = contactsModel.firstName
            mContactPhone.text = contactsModel.phone
        }
    }
}
```

Отправка:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is ContactsViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(contactsModel = mContactsList[position])

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val mIntentList: ArrayList<Contacts> = ArrayList()
                    val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("contact", mIntentList)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
                    context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Получение во второй Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        intent.getSerializableExtra("contact")
        details_first_name.text = intent?.extras?.getString("firstName")
        details_last_name.text = intent?.extras?.getString("lastName")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавлю ответ с общим примером, может кому-то понадобится. Для корректной работы проследите чтобы ваш класс "Model" реализовывал интерфейс Serializable или Parcelable (второй вроде как работает быстрее).
Класс Model:

```
data class Contacts(
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("notes")
    val notes: String,
    @SerializedName("images")
    val images: String?
) : Serializable
```

Адаптер:

```
class ContactsAdapter (private val context: Context, private val mContactsList: ArrayList<Contacts> = ArrayList())
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    fun setupContacts(contactsList: ArrayList<Contacts>) {
        mContactsList.clear()
        mContactsList.addAll(contactsList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_contact, parent, false)
        return ContactsViewHolder(itemView = itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mContactsList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is ContactsViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(contactsModel = mContactsList[position])

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val contactsModel: Contacts = mContactsList[position]
                    val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("contact", contactsModel)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
                    context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    class ContactsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mContactIcon: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image)
        var mContactFirstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_first_name)
        var mContactPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)

        fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
            contactsModel.images?.let { url ->
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                    .into(mContactIcon)
            }
            mContactFirstName.text = contactsModel.firstName
            mContactPhone.text = contactsModel.phone
        }
    }
}
```

И наконец вторая (принимающая) Activity:

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "DetailsActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        val clickedContact: Contacts = intent.getSerializableExtra("contact") as Contacts

        details_first_name.text = clickedContact.firstName
        details_last_name.text = clickedContact.lastName
        details_phone.text = clickedContact.phone
        details_email.text = clickedContact.email
        details_notes.text = clickedContact.notes

        Picasso.with(this@DetailsActivity).load(clickedContact.images).into(details_image)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для перехода на другую вьюшку, я вам советую в адаптер передать какой-то массив идентификаторов контактов, либо данные на каждый контакт. Дальше, вам нужно обработать нажатие на элемент списка:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ContactsViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(ctx, ContactDataActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("some_data", data)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
            ctx.startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
```

пример выше из моего проекта но думаю суть будет понятна. Вы при нажатии на элемент в интент прикладываете данные контакта. Есть два варианта:

1. Вы шлете в активность идентификатор контакта, а в активности вытаскиваете из интента идентификатор и шлете запрос в апи для получения информации про контакт.
2. Если апи для получения данных контакта нету, то шлете через интент всю нужную вам информацию, которую предварительно передали массивами в адаптер и вытаскиваете в вьюшке. [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intent.php) статья по поводу работы с интентом.

### UPDATE

При первом просмотре кода не заметил что вы шлете массив объектов)) Тогда все предельно просто - берете объект который находится на определенной позиции, и шлете его через интент:

```
intent.putExtra("ContactData", obj);
```

а в активности получаете его:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ContactData");
```

а дальше уже берете данные из пришедшего класса и отображаете, где вам нужно.

Comment: нет, obj это объект класса из массива который вы передаете в адаптер, его и передавайте. Получайте экз класса при нажатии на элемент списка, и дальше передавайте его

Comment: Что-то не так у меня идет. Во второй активити ничего не появляется, такое чувство как будто я через интент получаю пустые данные

Comment: а как вы их шлете? такое тоже может быть что вы ничего не получаете, можно попробовать через логи посмотреть что приходит

Comment: во второй активити в логах пусто. textView ничего не получает. Я не то передаю скорее всего в адаптере, уже запутался. Здесь чтобы показать код отправки надо вопрос обновить?

Comment: да, обновите пожалуйста если есть возможность :)

Comment: Добавил в конце вопроса

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102901/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and--).